# How do I create a checklist and destroy its items using ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am working on a rails assignment that needs me to create a checkbox that destroys items on a to-do list. I am currently getting a undefined local variable or method `item,' but I don't think thats the overall problem with my items#destroy action. Should I be making item to be @item instead?

Items Controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @item = Item.new(params.require(:item).permit(:name))
    @item.user_id = @user.id
     if @item.save
       flash[:notice] = "Item was saved."
       redirect_to [@user, @item]
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the item. Please try again."
       render :new
     end
   end

   def show
     @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
     @item = Item.find(params[:id])
   end

   def destroy
     @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
     @item = Item.find(params[:id])

     if @item.destroy
       flash[:notice] = "Item was removed."
     else
       flash[:error] = "Item couldn't be deleted. Try again."
     end

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.js
  end
end
```

Destroy.js.erb

```
$('#item-' +<%= @item.id %>).hide();
```

Users Show:

```
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-11">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 lead">User profile<hr></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
              <img class="img-circle avatar avatar-original" style="-webkit-user-select:none;
              display:block; margin:auto;" src="http://robohash.org/sitsequiquia.png?size=120x120">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h1 class="only-bottom-margin"><%= @user.email%></h1>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <span class="text-muted">Name:</span> <%= @user.name%><br>
                  <span class="text-muted">Id:</span> <%= @user.id %><br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <h3>User's To-Do List</h3>
                  <%= link_to "", item, method: :delete, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok', remote: true  %>
                  <%= render partial: 'items/item'%>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time your view is called (i.e. `destroy.js.erb`), `@item` will be destroyed. Just add a variable that caches the `item` id:

```
def destroy
     @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
     @item = Item.find(params[:id])

     @item_id = @item.id

     if @item.destroy
       flash[:notice] = "Item was removed."
     else
       flash[:error] = "Item couldn't be deleted. Try again."
     end

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.js
end
```

and then in your `destroy.js.erb`:

```
$('#item-' +<%= @item_id %>).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is being introduced in your view with the line:

```
<%= link_to "", item, method: :delete, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok', remote: true  %>
```

I don't see a setter for 'item' anywhere, which would prevent the link_to method from inferring its type and route.

What appears to be missing is a loop through the user's items, something along the lines of...

```
<h3>User's To-Do List</h3>
<% @user.items.each do |item| %>
  <%= link_to "", item, method: :delete, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok', remote: true  %>
  <%= render partial: 'items/item'%>
<% end %>
```

Note that this solution makes an assumption about the relationship between User and Item, specifically a has_many :items in the User.rb model.